# Maximize active split pane and toggle it

Tags: visual-studio-code, hotkeys

Is there a way to maximize the active splitted pane to full screen and hide other splitted panes.

Is there already a hotkey to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that does not seem to be a feature yet. What is [suggested in a VS Code GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16927) is to use the `Maximize Editor Group` or `Maximize Editor Group and Hide Sidebar` commands (using the command pallet). To reset the size to what it was before maximizing the group use the `Reset Editor Group Sizes` command (from the command pallet)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the "Zen mode":
https://techstacker.com/vscode-toggle-zen-mode/